# iPhone : How to get values from class in viewForAnnotation method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, mapkit

I am trying to show two images on Map on base of Points name.

```
@interface MyAnnotationClass : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    NSString *_name;
    NSString *_description;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D _coordinate;


}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

-(id) initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate;
```

ViewDidLoad method code :

```
mapView.delegate = self;
    //Initialize annotation
    MyAnnotationClass *commuterLotAnnotation=[[MyAnnotationClass alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( 39.047752, -76.850388)];
    commuterLotAnnotation.name = @"1";
    MyAnnotationClass *overflowLotAnnotation=[[MyAnnotationClass alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(  39.047958, -76.852520)];
    overflowLotAnnotation.name = @"2";

    //Add them to array
    self.myAnnotations=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:commuterLotAnnotation, overflowLotAnnotation, nil];

    //Release the annotations now that they've been added to the array
    [commuterLotAnnotation release];
    [overflowLotAnnotation release];

    //add array of annotations to map
    [mapView addAnnotations:_myAnnotations];
```

viewForAnnotation code :

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)MapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    static NSString *parkingAnnotationIdentifier=@"ParkingAnnotationIdentifier";

    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotationClass class]]){

        //Try to get an unused annotation, similar to uitableviewcells
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView=[MapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:parkingAnnotationIdentifier];
        //If one isn't available, create a new one
        if(!annotationView){
            annotationView=[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:parkingAnnotationIdentifier];
           /* if(imgCount == 0){
                annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"passenger.png"];
                imgCount = 1;
            }
            else if(imgCount == 1){
                annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"place.png"];
                imgCount = 0;
            }*/
           // if([((MyAnnotationClass)annotation).name isEqualToString: @"1"])
            // code to show image
        }
        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Now I want to access name member of MyAnnotationClass in viewForAnnotation to decide point and image on base of point. e.g.
  if([((MyAnnotationClass)annotation).name isEqualToString: @"1"])

but it does not work and show exception on ((MyAnnotationClass)annotation)

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `([((MyAnnotationClass)annotation).name isEqualToString: @"1"])` should be `([((MyAnnotationClass *)annotation).name isEqualToString: @"1"])`. You need to cast it to a pointer (*) to MyAnnotationClass.